# Fatal signal 11 when using Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-external-storage, storage-access-framework

I am trying to use Storage Access Framework to delete files from External SD Card. I am getting the access permission by having SD Card Root Uri and then using different methods of DocumentFile to access a particular document in file hierarchy. Here's how I am doing it

I am getting the access of External SD Card root using the following code -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                MainActivity.hub.startActivityForResult(intent, TREE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then I am saving the treeUri and asking for persistent permission

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == NoobDeleteConfirmManager.TREE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri treeUri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                // Get Uri from Storage Access Framework.
                treeUri = data.getData();
                NoobFileUtils.setTreeUri(treeUri);
            }
        }
    }

//In NoobFileUtils.setTreeUri
public static void setTreeUri(Uri treeUriParam) {
        if (treeUriParam == null)
            return;
        mTreeUri = treeUriParam;
        // Persist URI in shared preference so that you can use it later.
        // Use your own framework here instead of PreferenceUtil.
        new PrefUtils().setRootSDCardUriLollipop(mTreeUri);

        // Persist access permissions.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            MainActivity.hub.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(mTreeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

Then I am getting the absolutePath of the File I want to delete and trying to get a DocumentFile object of it.

```
File file = new File(absolutePath);
DocumentFile _documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
```

This absolute path is deep into the hierarchy of the External SD Card. However this is giving me a Segmentation Fault and no Exception at all. I have tried to use the following code too to get the DocumentFile from File -

```
document = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(MainActivity.hub, mTreeUri);
```

This is giving me the same issue. (`MainActivity.hub` is singleton to MainActivity. Don't blame me, I am just fixing the bugs here).

Isn't it supposed to be like this? What's the problem of accessing File residing inside SD Card with Root Uri permission only. Isn't why `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` was created instead of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` . I am using it in Marshmallow anyways, so it should work.

Here's the crash log for the segmentation fault I am getting.

```
                                                 --------- beginning of crash
09-06 23:25:50.070 20947-20957/com.app A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xc in tid 20957 (HeapTaskDaemon)
09-06 23:25:50.083 20947-20953/com.app A/art: art/runtime/debugger.cc:514] Check failed: c != nullptr 
09-06 23:25:50.177 356-356/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-06 23:25:50.177 356-356/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_Phone/ASUS_Z010_CD:6.0.1/MMB29P/13.8.26.36-20160624:user/release-keys'
09-06 23:25:50.177 356-356/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
09-06 23:25:50.177 356-356/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
09-06 23:25:50.177 356-356/? A/DEBUG: pid: 20947, tid: 20957, name: HeapTaskDaemon  >>> com.app <<<
09-06 23:25:50.177 356-356/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.189 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(412) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.189 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/20947/stat
09-06 23:25:50.197 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f9e03b000  x1   0000007f9e03f2e0  x2   0000000070efa980  x3   0000155555545400
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x4   000000000000002a  x5   0000000004fe8000  x6   0000007fa14767c8  x7   0000020000000000
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x8   00000055ad5652b0  x9   0000000000040000  x10  0000000012ca2300  x11  0000000012ca2380
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x12  00000000000004dd  x13  00000000000004dd  x14  0000000012cb3610  x15  0000000000080001
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x16  00000055ad5652b0  x17  0000007f9dc2b000  x18  00000055ad561320  x19  0000000000000016
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0005550000440000  x21  0000000012ca30b0  x22  0000000012ca3000  x23  0000007f8c3c4b90
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000000  x25  0000007f8c3c4b98  x26  0000000000000001  x27  0000000000400000
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000012c00000  x29  0000007f8c3c4ab0  x30  0000007f9dc2d1a4
09-06 23:25:50.198 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f8c3c4ab0  pc   0000007f9dc2cc68  pstate 0000000080000000


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.204 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE 
09-06 23:25:50.206 356-356/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000021ec68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6Object15VisitReferencesILb0ELNS_17VerifyObjectFlagsE0ENS_2gc9collector17MarkObjectVisitorENS5_29DelayReferenceReferentVisitorEEEvRKT1_RKT2_+64)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000021f1a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art2gc10accounting11SpaceBitmapILm8EE16VisitMarkedRangeINS0_9collector17ScanObjectVisitorEEEvmmRKT_+448)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000021fbdc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep15ScanGrayObjectsEbh+2600)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000220128  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep25RecursiveMarkDirtyObjectsEbh+24)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000002206d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep12MarkingPhaseEv+344)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000002209d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep9RunPhasesEv+732)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000212b48  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+296)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000243e1c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+2056)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000245688  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000268f3c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+80)
09-06 23:25:50.207 356-356/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 0000000001f3b56c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x1f3b000)


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.226 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(413) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.226 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/stat

                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.240 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE 


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.390 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] handle_packet() t->online(1) p->msg.arg0(414) p->msg.arg1(0) OPEN


                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.390 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] handle the adb command, and the command = adb shell:cat /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats | grep 10172

                                      [ 09-06 23:25:50.422 18966:18966 E/         ]
                                      [adb] cuurent command is A_CLSE 
09-06 23:25:50.457 356-356/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:580): avc: denied { search } for name="com.app" dev="mmcblk0p44" ino=601485 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-06 23:25:50.577 356-356/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:581): avc: denied { search } for name="com.app" dev="mmcblk0p44" ino=601485 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-06 23:25:50.587 356-356/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:582): avc: denied { search } for name="com.app" dev="mmcblk0p44" ino=601485 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-06 23:25:50.637 356-356/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:583): avc: denied { search } for name="com.app" dev="mmcblk0p44" ino=601485 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-06 23:25:50.637 356-356/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:584): avc: denied { search } for name="com.app" dev="mmcblk0p44" ino=601485 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-06 23:25:50.657 356-356/? W/debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:585): avc: denied { search } for name="com.app" dev="mmcblk0p44" ino=601485 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0

                                            --------- beginning of system
09-06 23:25:50.723 1727-21902/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.app/com.activity.MainActivity
09-06 23:25:50.724 356-356/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
09-06 23:25:50.724 356-356/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
09-06 23:25:50.725 1727-1897/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

Comment: "Isn't it supposed to be like this?" -- no. "However this is giving me a Segmentation Fault and no Exception at all" -- that is a little surprising, but I would not expect the code to work. I would have expected a more conventional crash through a `SecurityException`. "I have tried to use the following code too to get the DocumentFile from File" -- that should be fine, though you may run into problems depending on what you try doing with `document`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the reply. So why should it give SecurityException when I already have the permission using `takePersistableUriPermission()`, manifest based permission and RunTime Permissions. I just want to delete that file, but it's returning null `DocumentFile` in `fromTreeUri()` method, with segmentation fault after few seconds.

Comment: You cannot delete "External SD Card root", which is the only valid `Uri` that you have anywhere in this question. You should be able to create a `DocumentFile` on that `Uri` via `fromTreeUri()`. However, you have no reliable means of finding something specific inside of that tree. If you want to delete a particular file on removable storage, have the user pick the *file* via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Then use `fromSingleUri()` on `DocumentFile` with the `Uri` that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, and call `delete()` on the `DocumentFile`.

Comment: But if `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` doesn't give recursive access permission, then how come few File Explorers are using just SD Card root access permission and deleting the file which is not directly under SD Card Root? I have checked ES File Explorer particularly and that's why I thought it's possible to traverse through complete SD Card hierarchy and delete any file we want. Using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is the last resort for me.

Comment: They are displaying the contents of the tree. Presumably, they are using `listFiles()` and `getDisplayName()` on `DocumentFile` for that. So, at the point of the delete request, they have a `DocumentFile` associated with the list row that they can use. That's not reliable for finding some assumed specific existing file, because `getDisplayName()` could return anything, not necessarily a filename.

Comment: getName() always returns the correct filename for files on primary and external storages. Well as far as i have seen.